# CSS text align right while still maintaining equal padding left and right

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

This may seem very simple but so far I have had much trouble, I basically need the text in the p tag to be text aligned right while still maintaining equal padding left and right at all times, also the width of the p tag needs to be a max width 50% of its container, here is some code and a basic fiddle illustrating the question http://jsfiddle.net/edmundoto/v9r7keh2/

```
<p> This text needs to be right aligned but always maintain equal padding left and right</p>

p {
   text-align: right;
   background-color:red;
   color:white;
   font-size:20px;
   max-width:50%;
   float:right;
}
```

Comment: There isn’t even any padding in your code …

Comment: I left this open because adding padding did not make the padding equal on both sides, only on the right side

Comment: both padding is equal but stay in right side.I am right.

Comment: If by padding you mean that you want the `<p>` to be centered in screen but the text be right aligned, then remove the `float` and add a `margin: 0 auto;` - http://jsfiddle.net/v9r7keh2/2/

Comment: You will of course not get the same _visual_ “padding” at both sides of your paragraph – because the text will break at uneven positions on the left side, when you align it right. Only if it breaks in a way that by pure chance all lines of text will be the exact same length you could actually achieve that.

Comment: perhaps a better way of explaining this is I want the equivalent of margin: 0 auto; center horizontal alignment, except I want the padding to do this on the text inside the p tag instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope i solved your problem. I set both `padding` `padding-right:50px` and `padding-left:50px` and still stay right according to your requirement.

**[Live Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s7hLf6sm/)**

**Result:**

[image: result]

Comment: @EdmundRojas: Well then you did quite a poor job of _asking_ for it …

Comment: @EdmundRojas Could you please define `maintaining equal padding left and right at all times`?

Comment: both are equal always because given padding is same as 50px for left and right side.If you want to responsive code then you should give padding of both side in % then it calculate position when browser resize.

Answer (score 3):

I think you could achieve that by using the combination of `text-align: justify` and `text-align-last: right;`.

However since the browser support of `text-align-last` property is not that good, you could fake the effect by `direction: rtl;` declaration, as follows:

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/huwebe/1/edit)**

```css
p {
  text-align: justify; direction: rtl;

  max-width:50%;
  float:right;

  padding: 0 1em;

  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**Note #1:** `direction: rtl;` [may cause a trouble](http://jsbin.com/huwebe/2/edit) when the sentence ends by `.`, `!`, etc.

**Note #2** `box-sizing: border-box;` makes UAs calculate the `width`/`height` of the box including padding and borders. Which is supposed to work on IE8 and above.

Comment: Ive tried text-align:justify; the only problem is the text starts to have strange gaps between them and looks really bad when you do that

Comment: @EdmundRojas So what do you exactly mean by `while still maintaining equal padding left and right at all times`? Without using `justify`, how could it take place?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

**HTML Code:**

```
<div>
    <p class="middle">align center</p>
</div>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
p.middle{
    width:50%;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/v9r7keh2/3/

just wrap it in parent

```
div {
max-width:50%;
float:right;
}

p{
text-align: right;
background-color:red;
color:white;
font-size:20px;
padding:1em;
padding-right:10em;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't center the paragraph horizontally, it seems to be sitting left